# Got smaller query results using bigquery java api

Tags: java, resultset, google-bigquery

I used the java file here
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/gettingstartedwithjava
It worked perfectly before but since last weekend, every time when i ran it, it always return only 512 records for any query. And I tried the same query directly in web browser by bigquery, it returned 3000+ records. Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that you're just getting back the first page of results. Try either calling [setMaxResults](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Jobs.GetQueryResults.html#setMaxResults%28java.lang.Long%29)() or paging through the results you get back (by using the `pageToken` from the `GetQueryResultsResponse` to request the next page in a subsequent call to `getQueryResults(..)....execute();`